# How VPC sharing works

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-vpc, aws-vpc

I do not understand VPC sharing concept.

So I have my root account and under this account I've created two accounts: 
 - myVPCShare1
 - myVPCShare2
Both account have full administrator rights.

VPC sharing documentation says that it allows to share vpc's between accounts.

So I've created VPC (shareVPC) with subnet (sharedSubnet) using myVPCShare1 account and I switched to myVPCShare2 and I see both shareVPC sharedSubnet without doing VPC sharing.
Moreover, using myVPCShare1 I've created EC2 instance and I also can see this instance when I switch to myVPCShare2.

So my question is: 
Can someone explain me the purpose/usage of VPC sharing ?

Answer (score 3):

Here'e the basis of your misunderstanding:

> *So I have my root account and under this account I've created two accounts*

No, you haven't.  You've created two *users* in **the same** AWS account.

Those two users, the root user, and any other users of yours are all owned by the same AWS account, and thus see all the account's resources (such as the EC2 instance described above) as long as they have permission to do so.

VPC Sharing applies across account boundaries -- not within the same account.